# Flutter 2.5 flutter brightness is deprecated

Tags: flutter, themes

flutter AppBarTheme brightness is deprecated and recommend colorScheme
what is colorScheme and how to implement it

Comment: Checkout the guide here https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ColorScheme is A set of colors based on the [Material](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-and-palettes) color system that can be used to configure the color properties of most components.

you can use it like this

```
  static const ColorScheme colorSchemeLight = ColorScheme(
    primary: primaryColor,
    secondary: accentColor,
    surface: background,
    background: background,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    error: failurRed,
    onBackground: Colors.black,
    onError: Colors.white,
    onPrimary: Colors.white,
    onSecondary: Colors.white,
    onSurface: Colors.black,
    primaryContainer: primaryColor,
    secondaryContainer: accentColor,
  );
    mainTheme = ThemeData(
            appBarTheme: appBarTheme,
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primaryColor: primaryColor,
            colorScheme: colorSchemeLight,
            textTheme: viatoTextTheme,
            backgroundColor: background,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: background);
```